# Factoring N with encryption keys

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I need help on part c

Assume $N = pq$  where $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes.

(a) If $d \equiv e^{-1}$ modulo $\phi (N)$ , show $ed - 1$ is an even number:

$ed\equiv 1$ modulo  $\phi (N)$

$ed - 1 \equiv 0$ modulo  $\phi (N)$ and since $\phi (N)$ is even for n > 2 we have $ed - 1 = 2k$

(b) If $gcd(m, N) =  1$, what is $m^{ed  - 1}$ modulo N ?

$m^{ed -1}$

$m^{ed} m^{ -1}$

$mm^{-1} \equiv 1 $ modulo N

(c) If $ ed -1 \equiv 2^nL$, $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ and L is odd. If m has the property $m^L \not\equiv \pm 1$ modulo N and $m^{2L} \equiv 1$ modulo N. How can you find the factors of N?

For this question I'm not sure how to start it any help is appreciated

Comment: For starters, something's not right with part (a). You stated that $d\equiv e\pmod{\phi(N)}$ is given, but you start your proof with a totally different assumption that $ed\equiv 1\pmod{\phi(N)}$. If this is not given, then where does it come from? In fact, claim (a) as written in your post isn't even true. For example, consider $N=15=3\cdot5$, so $\phi(N)=\phi(15)=8$, and $e=d=2$; then $d\equiv e\pmod{\phi(N)}$, and yet $ed-1$ isn't even. Either something is missing here or something is misrepresented here.

Comment: @zipirovich I made a mistake it is $d \equiv e^{-1}$ modulo $\phi (N)$and have edited thank you

Comment: Where are these problems from?

Comment: Interesting questions, I'll put these on the take-home final for my number theory and cryptography course next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For part $(c)$, I think the problem is going for the following idea:
>
> Suppose that $m^{L} \not \equiv \{ \pm 1\} \pmod{N}$, and $m^{2L} \equiv 1 \pmod{N}$. Then $0 \ne m^{2L}-1 = (m^{L}-1)(m^{L}+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$. Then:
>
> $\{ gcd(N,m^{L}+1) , gcd(N,m^{L}-1)\} = \{ p,q \}$ for $N = pq$ because $m^{L}+1 , m^{L}-1 \ne 0$ and $m^{L}+1 , m^{L}-1$ each contain exactly one but not both prime factors by the assumption that $m^{L} \not \equiv \{ \pm 1\} \pmod{N}$.
>
> Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks that's just what I needed